# Why I need to click twice to view and save my data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can somebody help me regarding to my Ajax and jQuery? My problem is I need to click it twice to execute my codes. I separate my PHP code of View and Save. I wonder why this is happen there something wrong with my location? Always show this error "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.ciuvo.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')". I'm very new on Ajax and jQuery so I really need your help guys. If you want to see my PHP code I will provide it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#btnViewss").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url: "viewFuneral.php",
   method: "post",
   data: {btnViewss: ""},
   success: function(data){
    document.write(data);
   }
  });
 });



 $("#btnSavess").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"post",
   data:{btnSavess: "", firstName: $("#firstName").val(), middleName: $("#middleName").val(),  
   lastName: $("#lastName").val(), dob: $("#dob").val(), dod: $("#dod").val(), civilStatus: $("#txtStatus").val(),
   address: $("#txtAddress").val(), nameOfFather: $("#nameOfFather").val(), nameOfMother: $("#nameOfMother").val(), reservationDate: $("#reservationDate").val(),
   selectTime: $("#selectTime").val(),},
   success: function(data){
    alert(data);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/funeral.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
 <title>Parish - Funeral</title>
</head>
<body>
 <main>
 <a href="#">
  <h2 class="section-heading">Funeral</h2>
 </a>
 <form id="simpleForm">
  <div class="div-container">
   <label>Firstname :</label>
   <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Middlename :</label> 
   <input type="text" id="middleName" name="middleName" placeholder="Enter Middle Name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Lastname :</label> 
   <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Date of Birth :</label> 
   <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Date of Death :</label> 
   <input type="date" id="dod" name="dod">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Civil Status :</label> 
   <input type="input" id="txtStatus" name="civilStatus" placeholder="Enter Civil Status">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Address :</label> 
   <input type="input" id="txtAddress" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Name of Father :</label> 
   <input type="input" id="nameOfFather" name="nameOfFather" placeholder="Enter Father Name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Name of Mother :</label> 
   <input type="input" id="nameOfMother" name="nameOfMother" placeholder="Enter Mother Name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Reservation Date :</label> 
   <input type="date" id="reservationDate" name="reservationDate">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Select Time :</label> 
   <input type="time" id="selectTime" name="selectTime">
  </div>
  <div id="btnSubmit"><br><br>
   <button id="btnSavess">Save</button>
   <button id="btnViewss">View</button>
   <!-- <a href="reservation.php"><button type="button">Back</button></a> -->
  </div>
 </form><br><br>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this code inside an iFrame?

Comment: I don't know what is iFrame

Comment: Have you tried including your script inside the html instead of placing them in a separate file? There might be a problem with the url/paths.